# Convert JQuery to Plain Javascript: Add event listener to dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried most of the questions / answers available on stack overflow and can't seem to find a solution.

I am attempting to recreate the JQuery function in the code below to use Vanilla JavaScript.

JQuery is great and all, but I'm currently convert existing web pages to be JQuery free.

My biggest problem is traversing the dom, especially in tricky situations - like in the code below!

---

Here is a sample of the code:

```js
function getList() {
  let listURL = 'list.php';
  fetch(listURL)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      let html = '';
      html += `<ul class="col-sm-2 list-unstyled"><li><p class="title">Item List:</p></li>`;
      let counter = 0;
      let limit = 3;
      for (let key in data) {
        let d = data[key];
        html += `<li data-desk="${d.mReference}"><a><span class="d-title">${d['mDescription']}</span></a></li>`;
        if (++counter > limit) {
          html += `</ul><ul class="col-sm-2 list-unstyled"><li><p class="title">Item List:</p></li>`;
          counter = 0;
        }
      }
      html += `</ul>`;
      document.getElementById('itemList').insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', html);
    });
}

//This Works
$(document).on('tap touchstart click', '#itemList li', function(e) {
  var text = ($(e.target).closest('li').data('desk'));
  window.location.replace('dashboard.html#' + text);
  location.reload(true);
});
```

```html
<div class="row" id="itemList"></div>

<!-- DYNAMICALLY ADDED HTML -->
<ul class="col-sm-2 list-unstyled">
  <li>
    <p class="title">Machine:</p>
  </li>
  <li data-desk="item1"><a><span class="d-title">Item 1</span></a></li>
  <li data-desk="item2"><a><span class="d-title">Item 2</span></a></li>
  <li data-desk="item3"><a><span class="d-title">Item 3</span></a></li>
  <li data-desk="item4"><a><span class="d-title">Item 4</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I have tried different variations but with no joy:

```
document.addEventListener('click touchstart', function (e) {
if (e.target.matches('li')) {
    let selectedListItem = e.target.closest('li').data('desk');
    window.location.href = 'dashboard.html#' + selectedListItem 
    location.reload(true);
  }
}, false);


let dropDown = QSA('#itemList *');  //querySelectorAll
dropDown.addEventListener('click touchstart', function (e) {
if (e.target.matches('li')) {
    let selectedListItem = e.target.closest('li').data('desk');
    window.location.href = 'dashboard.html#' + selectedListItem 
    location.reload(true);
  }
}, false);


document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click touchstart', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'li') {
   let selectedListItem = e.target.closest('id').data('desk');
   window.location.href = 'dashboard.html#' + selectedListItem 
   location.reload(true);
  }
});

document.getElementById("itemList").addEventListener("click 
touchstart",function(e) {
  if (e.target && e.target.matches("ul li")) {
      let selectedListItem = e.target.closest('li').data('desk');
      window.location.href = 'dashboard.html#' + selectedListItem ;
      // window.location.replace('dashboard.html#' + selectedListItem 
      location.reload(true);
  }
}, false);
```

---

Any help / direction would be appreciated!

Comment: Use separate calls to [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to attach different event types.

Comment: Expanding on what @Teemu said... addEventListener only configures a single DOM event for the element. for example, you need both `document.addEventListener('click', function (e) {});` and `document.addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {});` also make sure you are using the events as defined for addEventListener as opposed to JQuery's shorthand -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Comment: Ah I see ontouchstart is the correct eventproperty

Answer (score 0):

So thank you to @Teemu and @daddygames for the direction.

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
let dropDown = document.querySelector('#itemList ul');
dropDown.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    if (e.target && e.target.nodeName == "LI") {
        let itemList = e.target.closest('li').getAttribute('data-desk');
        window.location.replace('dashboard.html#' + itemList);
        location.reload(true);
    }
});
},false);
```

The span elements within the li tags weren't bubbling up when clicked so added the folllowing class to them which worked a treat: `style="pointer-events: none;"`

I found this solution on css-tricks: [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/slightly-careful-sub-elements-clickable-things/)